# Include js in module

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm creating a module, I followed the officila tutorial, the basic module is working fine.
Now I want to add some JS.

From the official documentation, I tried the 2 methods advised in "myModule/tmpl/default.php". Doesn't look too complicated.

```php
<?php
JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'templates/custom/js/sample.js');
?>
```

And nothing happens, like nothing at all, looks like there's not even an attempt to grab the file from the server or any directory I put it in.

```php
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/media/system/js/sample.js');
?>
```

Nothing happens neither but there the object $document seems empty, so i suspect the problem is elsewhere. I'd prefer to use the 1st method which seems more modern.

note : the site is functional.

Comment: Where is the JS file located?

Comment: @Antoine I see that you've joined the Wordpress Stack Exchange community.  If you have Joomla questions, they can be posted at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.